# which tense should I use to describe my past experience at my previous company?

Tags: grammar, tense

I worked at company A before, and my friend asked me about my experience at company A. I was wondering if I should say

> my experience at A has been mostly great.

or

> my experience at A was mostly great.

Are there any better ways to say this? and what are the differences between these two?

Comment: Just use the simple past, you are no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is quite good and grammatically correct, as "was" is past tense, as you had "worked at A before", which is also past tense.

> my experience at A was mostly great.

This sentence however, makes your friend think that you still work at the company, as "has been" is present perfect tense, meaning it is still going on, so the first sentence is better.

> my experience at A has been mostly great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you no longer work for company A, you should say:

My experience in this company was mostly great.

If you say: My experience in this company has been mostly great.

It will translate as "I still work for that company." in your friend's mind.

Also, it's better to say "I used to work for that company" or "My experience in that company was great" rather than "at that company".